# Yii 2: how to build search query using ActiveRecord between 2 tables?

Tags: activerecord, yii2

I used Yii 2.

To be clear:

- The two tables, content and task, is 1:1 relation, task.content_id =
  content.id;
- and I referenced
  [doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#filtering-data).
- in view file, I used Gridview to show data.
- and I wanna the content is also searchable even it is in another
  table.

Maybe the following sql can explain what I want:

```
SELECT 
    c.content, 
    t.publish_status 
FROM 
    content c, task t 
WHERE 
    c.content LIKE '%keywordInContent%' AND
    t.publish_status = 1 AND
    c.id = t.content_id 
ORDER BY 
    updated_at 
LIMIT 20;
```

Here is my controller code：

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new TaskSearch;
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->getRequest()->get());

    return $this->render('index', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
    ]);
}
```

and search model code:

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Task::find()->trashed(Task::TRASHED_NO);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere(['publish_status' => $this->publish_status]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

I have settled it by searching like clause before and adding the resulted content_id to searchModel query, code like follow:

```
if (!empty($this->keyword)) {
     $contentIdArr = Content::find()->select('id')->where(['like', 'content', $this->keyword])->column();
     if (empty($contentIdArr)) {
        $contentIdArr = -1;
     }
     $query->andFilterWhere(['content_id' => $contentIdArr]);
}
```

I wonder is there a way to construct the sql I wrote at begin in Yii 2 ?

thanks for help.

Comment: Taks and content is 1:1 relation? Do you use the GridView for your tasks and display the content as well? And now you want to make the content searchable as well? If so, please update your post to make this clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you try this:

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Task::find()->trashed(Task::TRASHED_NO);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    if(!empty($this->keyword))
        $query->leftJoin('content', 'content.id=task.content_id')
            ->andWhere(['publish_status' => 1])
            ->andWhere(['LIKE', 'content', $this->keyword])
            ->orderBy('updated_at');

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

But the updated_at shouldn't be part of the search, I guess. This is more about sorting. Look [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview/) for an example.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can do it by first getting Content data and have a relation with Task model.

You can achieve relation by this [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#working-with-relational-data). Relation in **Content** model:

```
public function getTask()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Task::className(), ['content_id' => 'id']);
}
```

and search query

```
$searchResult = Content::find()
            ->select('content, publish_status')
            ->with('task')
            ->where(['LIKE', 'content', 'keywordInContent'])
            ->andWhere(['publish_status' => 1])
            ->orderBy('updated_at')
            ->limit(20)
            ->all();
```

I think this might help you.